# Is MBaaS specifically for Hybrid applications or can also used for Native Applications?

Tags: native, backend, hybrid, mbaas

I am researching `MBaaS` (Mobile Backend as a Service) and what its purpose is, for school. So far I gathered that it is basically a resource that developers can use so they can create the back-end code one time, rather than separately for each device - this way the focus can be more on the front-end of the development.

So my initial thoughts would be that this tool can be used only in the creation of Hybrid apps, however I'm having difficulty finding information to back that thought up. So can `MBaaS` be applied to Native apps also?

If the sense of meaning I've gathered about what `MBaaS` is used for is wrong, making my original question void or not applicable, a thorough but *simple* explanation, of what exactly `MBaaS` does would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MBaaS is a service that can be used by all – companies that are big to start ups and solo developers.

Mobile app development remains fun when it is about designing user interfaces, engineering social communication among users or bringing in stickiness. The Backend infrastructure plumbing is too time consuming and less rewarding. Worrying about database scaling, thread locking, persistence, user registration handling, messaging and pushing notifications is not fun. They are necessary evils that have to be taken care of to launch an app. The Baas paradigm has definitely made app development much easier and fun. Hence MBaaS services definitely present a powerful case for quick adoption.

[Built.io Backend](https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview) is an [MBaaS provider](https://www.built.io). It is client platform agnostic. It provides [platform-specific SDKs](https://docs.built.io/downloads) (iOS as well as Android) for native app development, and Xamarin and JavaScript SDKs for hybrid app development.

Coming back to your question. MBaaS can be used to develop native as well as hybrid applications. The services is not limited to a platform or any other technology.

**PS:** I am employee at [built.io](https://www.built.io)